# Is there a way to split node module bundle file in webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, code-splitting

I built a Vuejs App for House Plan. I've already use some optimisation way but I have two node modules whose size are far up to 20kb and I get a bad score on performance test with lighthouse on google. Here the following module :

```
 dist\js\npm.bootstrap-vue.9bf0056f.js                228.65 KiB
 dist\js\npm.vue-tel-input.4440bc34.js                181.81 KiB
```

Please is there a way to split this?

Answer (score 0):

I initially started writing this answer as a "use async components" but I see that you have a problem with libraries that are huge (bootstrap-vue and vue-tel-input respectively), not eg. Vue Router views

Are you sure that you're importing eg. Bootstrap Vue components in an efficient way? Maybe you can avoid importing the enteriety of BootstrapVue and just use certain parts you need? https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#tree-shaking-with-module-bundlers

See
https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5439

As for vue-tel-input, are you using version 5? Looks like it's lighter. So hopefully it'll help you, since you can't really split someone else's library unless you fork it

https://github.com/iamstevendao/vue-tel-input/issues/213#issuecomment-764416297